# Fastest way to see if a entity's child table contains any records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

After reading: http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=22425&p=74949&hilit=IQueryable#p74949 
It seems like I should use `IQueryable` to figure out if a entity's child table has a record or not.

My initial attempt was like:
Ace.DirDs.Any();

This line of code (or similar lines of code) could be run hundreds of times and was causing a huge performance issue.

So from reading the previous post in the link above I thought I would try something like:

```
IQueryable<DirD> dddd = CurrentContext.DirDs
    .Where(d => d.AceConfigModelID == ace.ID).Take(1);
bool hasAChild = dddd.Any();
```

Would there be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for a `Take(1)`. Plus, this one is shorter to type.

```
bool hasAChild =  CurrentContext.DirDs.Any(d => d.AceConfigModelID == ace.ID);
```

Comment: I am having performace issues.  The code above could be run hundreds of times.  In my previous code (before the one I posted) I discovered that I was creating a IEnumerable and was loading potentially thousands of records into memory and then seeing if one existed.  Does your code prevent that from happening?

Comment: You need to make sure you're hitting an IQueryable instead of an IEnumerable. An IEnumerable will cause work to be done in memory rather than against a data source.

Comment: We'd need to see what type `CurrentContext.DirDs` is.

Comment: This answer seems to be the fastest way.  My original first way was doing something like:  entity.DirDs.Count() and that would take 22-26 seconds to complete.  While  CurrentContext.DirDs.Any(d => d.AceConfigModelID == ace.ID); takes 14-16 seconds.  I am running theses statements hundreds of times.  It's better but still slower than I would like.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I *think* `Any()` will still cause an initial `Read()` of the first row from the database server back to the client. You may be better getting a `Count` so you only get a number back:

```
bool hasAChild = CurrentContext.DirDs.Count(d => d.AceConfigModelID == ace.ID) > 0;
```

By the way this doesn't appear to be looking at a child table just `DirDs`.

Comment: Sorry my initial attempt was looking at a child table and that was causing a huge performance issue.  So I am trying to use IQueryable to avoid that issue.

Comment: `Count()` will result in a lot more I/O on the server than is needed. `Any()` will not return any of the data.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are materializing the IQueryable into an IEnumerable, and so the entire query is executed and you are then only just taking the first row in the result. Either of the previously exampled answers will be exponentially faster than this. Be careful when using Count as there is both a property Count and a method Count(). In order to avoid your original problem (and if you choose the Count route), you'll want to use the method Count() like in Rhumborl's example, otherwise it'll execute the query and give you the property Count of your IEnumerable that was returned. The method Count() essentially translates into a SQL COUNT whereas the method Any() translates into a SQL EXISTS (at least when working with Microsoft SQL Server). One can be more efficient than the other at this level depending on what your backend database is and which version of EF you're using.

My vote would be to always default to Any() and explore Count() if you run into performance troubles. There can still be performance costs with the method Count() at the database level, but that still depends on the database you're using.

Here's a good related answer: [Linq To Entities - Any VS First VS Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429185/linq-to-entities-any-vs-first-vs-exists)