# Unexpected behavior when checking for existing records in the database

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, ember-data

I have an ASP.NET CORE 2.1 API back-end with an Ember front-end (created in VSCode). I am following an online video tutorial from Embercasts for new-user registration. The logic for checking for duplicate users is not working properly:

```
if (context.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((string) value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count() > 1)
{
     return new ValidationResult("Username is already taken", new [] { "Username" });
}
```

For some reason, the code above allows for exactly one duplicate user before reporting a duplicate user. In other words, the code to return a new ValidationResult alerting the user of a duplicate record is not reached. I figured that this may be related to some bizarre array indexing issue, where the first record is in position 0. After testing that hypothesis, I was proven correct. The following code prevents duplicates, while still allowing for one record to be created:

```
if (context.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((string) value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0)
{
     return new ValidationResult("Username is already taken", new [] { "Username" });
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any help is appreciated.

**LibraryApi\Model\User.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using JsonApiDotNetCore.Models;

namespace LibraryApiNew.Models
{
    public class User : Identifiable
    {
        [Attr("email"), UniqueEmail, Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]public string Email {get; set; }
        [Attr("username"), UniqueUsername, Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]public string Username { get; set; }
        [Attr("password"), NotMapped, Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false), Compare("PasswordConfirmation")]public string Password { get; set; }
        [Attr("password-confirmation"), NotMapped, Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]public string PasswordConfirmation { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }

    public class UniqueUsername : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var context = (AppDbContext) validationContext.GetService(typeof(AppDbContext));

            if (context.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((string) value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0) // Why?
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Username is already taken", new [] { "Username" });
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }

    public class UniqueEmail : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var context = (AppDbContext) validationContext.GetService(typeof(AppDbContext));

            if (context.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals((string) value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0) // Why?
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Email is already taken", new [] { "Email" });
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong here? If you check with `>1` there will always be at least 2 entries? I would say the first check is simply incorrect

Comment: @LennartStoop The more I think about it, you are right - it should be greater than 0. But, I swear, I am not crazy; the video shows count > 1 and the trainer gets the correct behavior. The only thing that makes sense is that in the video tutorial, the database table is not shown. So, it is possible that the trainer has duplicate records in the database and does not even know it.

Comment: The `Count() >0` does excactly one thing: It checks if the username is already present. If yes, this would allow or a duplicate to be created.  So this is correct

Comment: @Marco You are correct. I'm thinking the video tutorial has an error. Not the code.

Comment: @JWeezy, if you can get in touch with the tutorial author and make him aware of it. I think he might be grateful.

Comment: @Marco I have sent them an e-mail. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code relates to user registration and the if clause with `context.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((string) value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0` does check if the username is already present.

If it is present, creating a second one would create a duplicate, hence the error message "Username is already taken".

If the count is 0, that simply means, that name is not yet taken and can be used and the validation succeeds.

Now would you check for `> 1`, that would mea, that you would willingly allow for one duplicate

Comment: Thank you for providing a second set of eyes. After thinking about it further, that makes sense logically. I think the reason that it looks correct in the tutorial is that there is an error in the tutorial where one duplicate record already existed and the trainer doesn't even realize it.

Comment: If you're using SQL server, the default collation is CI (Case Insensitive) so you may not even need the `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.  Secondly, since you're simply looking for any record, count() is inefficient, instead consider [Any()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429185/linq-to-entities-any-vs-first-vs-exists).

Answer (score 2):

I know that this should be placed in comments but I didn't have that much reputation so to sum up your checks.

You can alter your checking to be

```
if (context.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((string) value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Count() >= 1)
{
     return new ValidationResult("Username is already taken", new [] { "Username" });
}
```

Another alternative for your check and won't mislead you is

```
if (context.Users.Any(u => u.Username.Equals((string) value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
     return new ValidationResult("Username is already taken", new [] { "Username" });
}
```